# optimize a query with a pseudo-recursive function in it mysql

Tags: mysql, function, optimization

I wonder how to optimize a query which has a function within.
Specifically, take

```
select all_couples.*,
       getCoauth(PersA, PersB, Prio_year) as PastCoauth
from all_couples
```

and the function is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getCoauth`(pA INT(11), pB INT(11), y YEAR(4)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

RETURN (
select count(*)
from all_couples as d
where PersA=pA 
and PersB=pB
and Prio_year < y
);

END
```

the table I am working on is the following

```
Appln_id int(11) 
PersA int(11), index PersA
PersB int(11), index PersB 
Prio_year year(4), index Year
```

The table has 10.000.000 rows. It takes more than one hour to generate the select. If I run explain I get that it is not using keys on the query, but it does within the function properly.
I am wondering if the problem is that, using a function like mine, the same select on the whole table has been made for each row selected in the main query.

Any suggestion or reference for optimize something like this?

Comment: This is going to run the function for every row returned and is pretty horrible from a performance standpoint. Please checkout JOIN and GROUP BY

Comment: I tried to, but the problem is that, out of a function, I do not know how to model the `Prio_year<y`, that is: I need to count (and I can do it with a group by) all the rows where PersA AND PersB are equal BUT with a Prio_year smaller than the one the query is selecting. I have been looking for something like a `Prio_year<self` unsuccessfully. Do you have any useful suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(PersA, PersB, Prio_year)
```

That is a *composite* index.  It is *different* from what you have (3 separate indexes).  It will work much better in the example code you gave.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.